How i can resolved JpaRepository <> in Spring MVC
I am working on a Spring MVC project and I want to create a repository interface that extends JpaRepository. However, I'm encountering compilation errors indicating that some JAR files might be missing or there are conflicts between the JARs.
Here's my repository interface:
public interface  StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<Student , Long> {
}

I've included the following JAR files in my project:
antlr-2.7.7.jar
aopalliance-1.0.jar
aspectjrt-1.8.0.jar
commons-logging-1.1.3.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.4.Final.jar
hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar
hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.5.Final.jar
hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar
hsqldb-2.3.2.jar
jandex-1.1.0.Final.jar
javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar
javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar
javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-1.2.5.jar
jboss-logging-3.1.3.GA.jar
jboss-logging-annotations-1.2.0.Beta1.jar
jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar
jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.7.jar
jsp-api-2.1.jar
jstl-api-1.2.jar
serializer-2.7.2.jar
servlet-api-2.5.jar
slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar
spring-aop-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-data-commons-1.8.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-data-jpa-1.6.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-jdbc-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-orm-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-tx-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-webmvc-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar
xalan-2.7.2.jar

My Repository Class
package dao;
import entity.Student;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
@Repository
public interface StudentDao extends CrudRepository<Student, Long> {
    // methods if any
}

My Controller Class
package controller;

import dao.StudentDao;
import entity.Student;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import java.util.List;

@Controller
public class StudentController {

    @Autowired
     StudentDao studentDao;

    @RequestMapping("/student")
    public String studentList(Model model) {
        List<Student> students = (List<Student>) studentDao.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("users", students);
        System.out.println("List of students: " + students);
        System.out.println("Controller of students");
        return "student";
    }
}


ApplicationContext.xml is here
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd  
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">

    <!-- Load properties from application.properties -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location" value="/WEB-INF/application.properties" />
    </bean>
 <context:annotation-config />
    <!-- Enable MVC annotations -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <!-- Serve static resources -->
    <mvc:resources mapping="/reports/**" location="/WEB-INF/reports/" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="/WEB-INF/images/" />
    <mvc:resources location="/WEB-INF/resources/" mapping="/resources/**"/>

    <!-- Enable transaction management -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="jpaTransactionManager"/>

    <!-- Component scan for all relevant packages -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="controller, service, dao, config, dto,entity"/>

    <!-- Configure data source -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/springdb" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="root" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Configure JPA EntityManagerFactory -->
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="entity.Student" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <!-- Set Hibernate dialect -->
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
                <!-- Show SQL queries in console for debugging -->
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <!-- Automatically update database schema -->
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Configure JPA Transaction Manager -->
    <bean id="jpaTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

</beans>


Errors in console i am facing
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'studentController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: dao.StudentDao controller.StudentController.studentDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [dao.StudentDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:293)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1186)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)


remove javax.persistence-api-2.2.jar

after removing still not working/resolving compilation error

show your pom.xml and more exception message ?

spring boot application  or web application war ?

I'm working with Spring MVC and not using Spring Boot, which is why I'm not utilizing a POM.xml file. Instead, I've downloaded the necessary JAR files manually and added them to the classpath for my project in Spring MVC

I update the Answer , use Spring MVC 4.

Update

apache-tomcat-9.0.90
JDK 1.8.0_412
spring-core-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-orm-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-data-jpa-1.6.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-webmvc-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar

UPDATE Eclipse Dynamic Web WAR
hello-tomcat9-web$ tree
.
└── src
    └── main
        ├── java
        │   └── com
        │       └── example
        │           ├── controller
        │           │   └── UserController.java
        │           ├── model
        │           │   └── User.java
        │           └── repository
        │               └── UserRepository.java
        └── webapp
            ├── META-INF
            │   └── MANIFEST.MF
            └── WEB-INF
                ├── lib
                │   ├── antlr-2.7.7.jar
                │   ├── aopalliance-1.0.jar
                │   ├── aspectjrt-1.8.0.jar
                │   ├── commons-logging-1.1.3.jar
                │   ├── dom4j-1.6.1.jar
                │   ├── hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.4.Final.jar
                │   ├── hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar
                │   ├── hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.5.Final.jar
                │   ├── hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar
                │   ├── hsqldb-2.3.2.jar
                │   ├── jandex-1.1.0.Final.jar
                │   ├── javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar
                │   ├── javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar
                │   ├── javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-1.2.5.jar
                │   ├── jboss-logging-3.1.3.GA.jar
                │   ├── jboss-logging-annotations-1.2.0.Beta1.jar
                │   ├── jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar
                │   ├── jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.7.jar
                │   ├── jsp-api-2.1.jar
                │   ├── jstl-api-1.2.jar
                │   ├── serializer-2.7.2.jar
                │   ├── servlet-api-2.5.jar
                │   ├── slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar
                │   ├── spring-aop-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar
                │   ├── spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar
                │   ├── spring-context-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar
                │   ├── spring-core-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar
                │   ├── spring-data-commons-1.8.0.RELEASE.jar
                │   ├── spring-data-jpa-1.6.0.RELEASE.jar
                │   ├── spring-expression-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar
                │   ├── spring-jdbc-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar
                │   ├── spring-orm-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar
                │   ├── spring-tx-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar
                │   ├── spring-web-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar
                │   ├── spring-webmvc-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar
                │   ├── xalan-2.7.2.jar
                │   └── xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar
                ├── spring
                │   ├── application-context.xml
                │   └── dispatcher-config.xml
                ├── views
                │   └── index.jsp
                └── web.xml

User.java
package com.example.model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

UserRepository.java
package com.example.repository;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import com.example.model.User;

public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {
}

UserController.java
package com.example.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import com.example.model.User;
import com.example.repository.UserRepository;

@Controller
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("users", userRepository.findAll());
        return "index";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/add",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addUser(@RequestParam String name) {
        User user = new User();
        user.setName(name);
        userRepository.save(user);
        return "redirect:/";
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/del",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String delUser(@RequestParam Long id) {
        userRepository.delete(id);        
        return "redirect:/";
    }    
}

index.jsp
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
    
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>User List</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>User List</h1>
    <form action="add" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter user name" required />
        <input type="submit" value="Add User" />
    </form>
    <ul>
        <c:forEach items="${users}" var="user">
            <li>${user.id} - ${user.name} - 
 <a href="<c:url value='/del'><c:param name='id' value='${user.id}'/></c:url>">Delete User</a>
            </li>
        </c:forEach>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>

dispatcher-config.xml
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.example" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <mvc:default-servlet-handler />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
</beans>

application-context.xml
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.example" />
    <context:annotation-config />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testdb" />
        <property name="username" value="sa" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.example.model" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
                <property name="showSql" value="true" />
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven />

    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.example.repository" />
</beans>

web.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="4.0">
  <display-name>hello-tomcat9-web</display-name>
  
      <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/dispatcher-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/application-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>  
</web-app>

lib jar list
antlr-2.7.7.jar
aopalliance-1.0.jar
aspectjrt-1.8.0.jar
commons-logging-1.1.3.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.4.Final.jar
hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar
hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.5.Final.jar
hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar
hsqldb-2.3.2.jar
jandex-1.1.0.Final.jar
javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar
javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar
javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-1.2.5.jar
jboss-logging-3.1.3.GA.jar
jboss-logging-annotations-1.2.0.Beta1.jar
jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar
jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.7.jar
jsp-api-2.1.jar
jstl-api-1.2.jar
serializer-2.7.2.jar
servlet-api-2.5.jar
slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar
spring-aop-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-data-commons-1.8.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-data-jpa-1.6.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-jdbc-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-orm-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-tx-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-webmvc-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar
xalan-2.7.2.jar

Eclipse export WAR
export WAR = hello-t9-web.war
Deploy to Tomcat 9
put hello-t9-web.war to Tomcat9/webapps
Start Tomcat 9
Test
Open "http://localhost:8080/hello-t9-web"
Add user

input "aaa" then click button
input "bbb" then click button
input "ccc" then click button

Delete User

Click link Delete User


TIPS
Based on the information you provided, the only things I can help with are the following:
You can jump directly to the following paragraph Jar List to see if you have the following files?
pom.xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>helloworldwebapp</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>helloworld Maven Webapp</name>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>helloworld</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.4.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

get all dependency jars
mvn dependency:copy-dependencies -DoutputDirectory=target/libs

dependency jars List
target/libs
├── antlr4-runtime-4.13.0.jar
├── jakarta.annotation-api-2.0.0.jar
├── jakarta.persistence-api-3.2.0.jar
├── micrometer-commons-1.12.7.jar
├── micrometer-observation-1.12.7.jar
├── slf4j-api-2.0.2.jar
├── spring-aop-6.1.9.jar
├── spring-beans-6.1.9.jar
├── spring-context-6.1.9.jar
├── spring-core-6.1.9.jar
├── spring-data-commons-3.3.1.jar
├── spring-data-jpa-3.3.1.jar
├── spring-expression-6.1.9.jar
├── spring-jcl-6.1.9.jar
├── spring-jdbc-6.1.10.jar
├── spring-orm-6.1.10.jar
└── spring-tx-6.1.9.jar

Jar List

spring-orm-6.1.10.jar
jakarta.persistence-api-3.2.0.jar
spring-data-jpa-3.3.1.jar

Now please check the jar file in the following list. Have you downloaded it?

antlr4-runtime-4.13.0.jar
jakarta.annotation-api-2.0.0.jar
micrometer-commons-1.12.7.jar
micrometer-observation-1.12.7.jar
slf4j-api-2.0.2.jar
spring-aop-6.1.9.jar
spring-beans-6.1.9.jar
spring-context-6.1.9.jar
spring-core-6.1.9.jar
spring-data-commons-3.3.1.jar
spring-expression-6.1.9.jar
spring-jcl-6.1.9.jar
spring-jdbc-6.1.10.jar
spring-tx-6.1.9.jar

dependency-tree
mvn dependency:tree

+- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:3.3.1:compile
|  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:3.3.1:compile
|  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:6.1.9:compile
|  |  +- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:6.1.9:compile
|  |  \- io.micrometer:micrometer-observation:jar:1.12.7:compile
|  |     \- io.micrometer:micrometer-commons:jar:1.12.7:compile
|  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:6.1.9:compile
|  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:6.1.9:compile
|  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:6.1.9:compile
|  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:6.1.9:compile
|  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:6.1.9:compile
|  +- org.antlr:antlr4-runtime:jar:4.13.0:compile
|  +- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:jar:2.0.0:compile
|  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:2.0.2:compile
+- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:6.1.10:compile
|  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:6.1.10:compile
\- jakarta.persistence:jakarta.persistence-api:jar:3.2.0:compile

It is recommended that :
(1) you create an empty directory,
(2) then generate a pom.xml (as I provided above),
(3) and then execute the mvn dependency:copy-dependencies -DoutputDirectory=target/libs command,
(4) you can obtain all dependent jar files in the target/libs directory at once , and then copy it to your webapp project.

Should I download the exact versions specified in the JAR list, or is it acceptable to use versions that are not precisely matched? Additionally, I want to mention that I am using Java version 1.8. Since I am not utilizing a pom.xml, I need to manually download these JAR files.

(1) First browse https://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html
(2) Confirm the Tomcat version you want to use
(3) Then confirm, which Servlet Spec version do you want to use? 6 or 4? (This will affect whether it uses javax.* or jakarta.* by default)
(4) Tomcat 10.1 uses jakarta.*, Servlet Spec 6
(5) The latest version of Spring Framework 6 requires JDK 17+
(6) Spring Framework 5.3.x: JDK 8-19 (expected)

(7) Please confirm first whether you are restricted to use JDK 1.8 (JDK 8)? If so, you should not use spring-data-jpa 3.3.1 (because spring-data-jpa 3.3.1 depends on Spring 6 ), and similarly for other package versions, if they have dependencies on Spring 6, you should not use them. You must use an older version instead.

(1) JDK version (JDK 1.8 or JDK 17)
(2) Java EE 8 or Jakarta EE 10 ?
(3) Tomcat version ?  Tomcat 9 or Tomcat 10.1
(4) Spring 5.3 or Spring 6 ?

I know that your webapp project does not use pom.xml, so there is no need to modify your project. My suggestion is that you create another empty directory and just put the pom.xml I provided into this empty directory. Yes. Then execute mvn dependency:copy-dependencies -DoutputDirectory=target/libs to download all jars at once.

I'm using Tomcat 9.0 for my server. Additionally, I'm working with NetBeans 8.2, which defaults to Spring Framework 4.0.1. Just to confirm, I'm using Java version 1.8.

I've downloaded the JAR files with the exact versions you specified and added them to the classpath, but the compilation error persists.

you should not use spring-data-jpa 3.3.1 (because spring-data-jpa 3.3.1 depends on Spring 6.

then which version should i use?

maybe spring-data-jpa 1.7.2.RELEASE, it depends on spring-core:jar:4.0.7.RELEASE (your limition: Spring Framework 4.0.1) , I use mvn dependency:tree to find out dependy tree.

after adding spring-data-jpa 1.7.2.RELEASE now its give this error message in console   `Compiling 16 source files to C:\Users\DELL\Documents\NetBeansProjects\BirtProject\build\web\WEB-INF\classes
C:\Users\DELL\Documents\NetBeansProjects\BirtProject\src\java\dao\StudentDao.java:17: error: cannot access PagingAndSortingRepository
public interface StudentDao  extends JpaRepository<Student , Long>{
bad class file: C:\Users\DELL\Downloads\JPA Jar files\spring-data-commons-3.3.1.jar(org/springframework/data/repository/PagingAndSortingRepository.class)
`

Ask AI the following questions: "tomca 9 war JDK 1.8 Spring 4.0.1 Minimal example using Spring MVC and Spring Data JPA". (I guess you need a minimal example of a webapp (war), AI, which can be CharGPT or something else. This will make it easier for you to get a minimal executable example.)

spring-data-jpa 1.7.2.RELEASE depends on spring-data-commons 1.9.2.RELEASE.

java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactoryService has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0 (unable to load class [org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactoryService])   at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2475)

(1) Check the version of Apache Commons Logging you are using, use an older version. (The newer version may be compiled with JDK 17 and cannot be executed in the Runtime of JDK 1.8) (52.0 -> JDK 1.8 , 61.0 -> JDK 17 , ) (2)  If my answer does not solve your problem, please do not set it as accepted.

@Bilal Kundi - I updated the answer and provided a war project that can be executed using JDK 1.8, Springg 4, and Tomcat 9.

All compilation error are now resolved but runtime errors are still present in console here is exact error org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'studentController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private dao.StudentDao controller.StudentController.studentDao

i have restricted to answer that's i am giving in comments otherwise i want to share my applicationContext.xml where i think something is missing please how i can share my code as whole

can you share the project you have run spring 4 with tomcat 9?

the project you have created share at irfankundi786@gmail.com with all jar file

What I posted is the complete content of the project, including the directory structure, file list, and file content. You only need to paste the content into your own file to run it. I have confirmed that the project can be deployed to Tomcat for execution, so that’s why There is a screen during execution.

I want the whole project with jar file actually struggling to download the jar file with same version each time there is some conflict.

after all setting done i have faced this error org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'studentController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private dao.StudentDao controller.StudentController.studentDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [dao.StudentDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which  

StudentDao is `package dao;
import entity.Student;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
@Repository
public interface StudentDao extends JpaRepository<Student, Long> {
// methods if any
}
`

controller is
`package controller;
@Controller
public class StudentController {
@Autowired
private StudentDao studentDao;

@RequestMapping("/student")
public String studentList(Model model) {
    List<Student> students = studentDao.findAll();
    model.addAttribute("users", students);
    System.out.println("List of students: " + students);
    System.out.println("Controller of students");
    return "student";
}

}`

i am restricted to post the answer thats why i am giving all code in comments                        Sorry, we are no longer accepting answers from your account because most of your answers need improvement or do not sufficiently answer the question. See the Help Center to learn more.

You can append your project in your question. just click edit.

question is update as i can not find append to attach the project

i have the question and all the details along with the error message shown in console
